# how to do casecading in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

i want casecading in cakephp. I am creating city manager where  I have two things zones and states as a dropdown. if i select zone then states should come according to selected zone.please help me what should be the code for model view and controller.I am new in cakephp. table for cities table is given below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cities` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `zone_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `state_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `total_sample` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `population` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `cities`
--

INSERT INTO `cities` (`id`, `zone_id`, `state_id`, `name`, `code`, `total_sample`, `population`, `is_active`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES
(1, 2, 2, 'avadi', '15018', 10, 100, 1, '2016-10-03 00:00:00', '2016-10-03 00:00:00');
```

Please help me with code for controller, view and model.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by 2 ways

1. Using [Chained](https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained) javascript library. in this way you have to format dropdown. for doing this you can follow [This Tutorial](http://mzm-cakephp.blogspot.com/2015/03/dropdown-cakephp-with-chained-selects.html)
2. By using Ajax request according to select Zone and State

***For Option 2***: Html

```
echo $this->Form->input('zone_id', ['options' => $zons, 'empty' => '','id'=>'zoneDropdown']);
echo $this->Form->input('state_id', ['options' => $state, 'empty' => '','id'=>'stateDropdown']);
echo $this->Form->input('city', ['options' => [], 'empty' => '','id'=>'cityDropdown']);
```

Ajax Script for Html

```
$('#zoneDropdown, #stateDropdown').on('change', function (evt) {
    ZONE = $("#zoneDropdown").val();  
    STATE = $("#stateDropdown").val();  
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: baseURL+"cities/getCitiesOptions/"+ZONE+"/"+STATE,
      dataType: "json",
      success : function(returnData) {
          $("#cityDropdown").val(returnData);  
        }
    });
});
```

and the controller Function need to add

```
 Public function getCitiesOptions($zone_id=null, $state_id=null){
    $conditions = [];
    if (!empty($zone_id)) {
        $conditions['Cities.zone_id'] = $zone_id;
    }
    if (!empty($state_id)) {
        $conditions['Cities.state_id'] = $state_id;
    }

    $cities = $this->Cities->find('all',['conditions'=>$conditions])->all()->toArray();
    // make Options for dorpdown
    $html = '';
    foreach ($cities as $key => $value) {
        $html .= '<option value="'.$value['code'].'">'.$value['name'].'</option>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: nd what about ajax request?

Comment: @sukh ok I am updating my answare

Comment: I am not getting any value in dropdown. In zone the data should come from zone table, according to the zone_id..but nothing is coming

Comment: **$zons** and **$state** variable need to set form the controller with data. i think it's easy part